# What is this texture for?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was making a texture pack when I saw this:

[image]

What is this texture for?

Comment: Is there some minecraft notation for that sprite location? Including the location's name would hlep googability

Comment: @BenBrocka They are numbered 0–255. 0 is the top left, 15: top right, 255: bottom right, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [this wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Texture), it's the texture for the [Ender Dragon Egg](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dragon_Egg):

[image]

Comment: No that texture has lots of blue streaks.

Comment: @DutchClark: Right, corrected my answer. ;)